# Cannot load sound later during runtime

Tags: java, audio

Hello I have created little class to play sounds in my game. Here:

package sk.tuke.oop.game.sounds;

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;

public class Sound implements AudioClip {

    private Clip clip;
    private FloatControl volume;
    private int framePosition;

    public Sound(String path) {
        loadMusic(path);
    }

    public void loadMusic(String path) {
        if (clip != null)
            clip.stop();

        clip = null;

        if (!path.equals("")) {

            File soundFile = null;

            try {
                soundFile = new File(path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                clip = null;
            }

        }

    }

    public void play() {
        if (clip != null) {
            stop();
            clip.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (clip != null) {
            clip.stop();
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (clip != null) {
            if (clip.isRunning()) {
                framePosition = clip.getFramePosition();
                clip.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public void unpause() {
        if (clip != null) {
            if (!clip.isRunning()) {
                clip.setFramePosition(framePosition);
                clip.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void loop() {
        if (clip != null) {
            clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
    }

    public void setVolume(float vol) {
        if (volume.getMinimum()+ vol <= volume.getMaximum()) {
            volume.setValue(volume.getMinimum());
            volume.setValue(volume.getValue() + vol);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine when all actors are created before game loop but when I shoot a bullet and I want to play a sound i get:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

Could you help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: Definitely mysterious, as the format you list is one that is normally supported by Java. You say the error occurs on the play(), not the loadMusic()? That suggests Java is okay with reading the file (you should verify the file is loaded as part of the debugging), but that the machine you are using will not play back that file format. Does you computer perhaps prefer big-endian? or otherwise not support the format? I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

if the sound file is not in mp3 format, then try to converted in mp3.
Also make sure that the file name is in lowercase letters.